# Text reveal animation

Tags: css, gsap

I got the animation that i want but it does not quite start from the place i want it to. The text should "come out" of the line, right now it doesn't quite do that. 
https://jsfiddle.net/bfth5w1k/

```
.text {
        margin: 100px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        position: absolute;
      }

 h1{    
        font-size: 80px;
        line-height: 200px;
        width: 600px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 80px;
        opacity:1;
        }
 h2{    
        font-size: 70px;
        line-height: 30px;
        width: 600px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0; 
        left: 80px;
        opacity:0;
        }
h3{    
        font-size: 60px;
        line-height: 150px;
        width: 600px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0; 
        left: 80px;
        opacity:0;
        }

.line {
        position: absolute;
        width: 500px;
        left: 80px;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: white;
      }
```

```
  
 gsap.from(".line", { width: 0, duration: 0.3 });
 gsap.from("h1",{height:0,duration:3,delay:0.3,opacity:0})
 gsap.to("h2",{height:0,duration:3,delay:0.3,opacity:1})
 gsap.to("h3",{height:0,duration:3,delay:0.3,opacity:1})
```

I can't figure this out, the css needs some tweaking maybe?

Comment: _"The text should 'come out' of the line"_ - Do you mean to say that, for any text that crosses the threshold of the line, any portion should be invisible on the side of the line it starts from and portions seen only as they cross the line?

Comment: Yes. That is what i mean, but also the text should be at that cross-point already  as the animation starts, so half of the animation is not wasted on the text being invisible.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, then this should do what you wanted.

```js
gsap.from(".line", {
  width: 0,
  duration: 0.3
});
gsap.from("h1", {
  height: 0,
  duration: 3,
  delay: 0.3,
  opacity: 0
})
gsap.to("h2", {
  height: 0,
  duration: 3,
  delay: 0.3,
  opacity: 1
})
gsap.to("h3", {
  height: 0,
  duration: 3,
  delay: 0.3,
  opacity: 1
})
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: violet;
}

.text {
  margin: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 80px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: -1;
  /*here*/
}

h2 {
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 80px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 150px;
  width: 600px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 80px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  /*here*/
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  left: 80px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 2;
}

.cover-up {
  background-color: violet;
  position: absolute;
  top: 105px;
  left: 180px;
  height: 205px;
  width: 500px;
  z-index: 1;
  /*here*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.7.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">

  <h1>Up</h1>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <h2>Down</h2>
  <h3>Down2</h3>

</div>
<div class="cover-up"></div>
```

I added a div element just above the line, and then used z-index to place the div in-between the different pieces of text.

Comment: I took the credit of moving your solution into a runnable snippet.  It appears to work for the text coming down, but not the text heading up...

Comment: OK, I changed it so that all of the text is hidden beyond the line. I thought that they wanted "down2" to be the only one hidden by the line.

Comment: I _think_ that they want "Up" to be _hidden_ until it crosses the line, but I could be misunderstanding-- the OP may have to weigh in.

Comment: I changed it again. Hopefully this is now correct.

Comment: Well, now it looks right for "Up" but "down" is hidden-- I think they wanted _both_ hidden.  But again, this is probably up to the OP to clarify.